# How to best secure MongoDB database url in Node.js app

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have an API built on MongoDB and Node.js. In my `app.js` I have a database url that I need to include, with a password in the url. Is there a secure way to define this url as a variable in another file for when it is deployed? I will likely be using Heroku to deploy this.

**app.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const product = require("./routes/product.route"); // Imports routes for the products
const app = express();

// Set up mongoose connection
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
// Change db url for new apps
let dev_db_url = "URL FOR MONGODB DATABASE TO BE SECURE";
const mongoDB = process.env.MONGODB_URI || dev_db_url;
mongoose.connect(mongoDB, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true, useFindAndModify: false });
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
const db = mongoose.connection;
db.on("error", console.error.bind(console, "MongoDB connection error:"));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using Heroku, the best way to store credentials is to define them as [config vars](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars) which can then be accessed from `process.env` in Node.js.